# Unexpected behavior using Autolayout with NSSplitView

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, autolayout, nssplitview

I have the following implemented with springs and struts along with several `NSSplitViewDelegate` resizing and constraint methods and it all works as desired.  I am now trying to adopt `autolayout` for this same scenario by replacing all of the `setFrame` messages and `NSSplitViewDelegate` methods with proper `autolayout` constraints.

My main window's view contains a vertical split view (I call OuterSplitter) with the top, bottom, left and right leading and trailing space constraints set to zero for OuterSplitter to its superview.

The right pane of OuterSplitter contains (among a few other things) another vertical split view (I call InnerSplitter)  which also has the top, bottom, left and right leading and trailing space constraints set to zero for InnerSplitter to its `superview` (i.e. OuterSplitter's right pane).

I have set nominal minimum width constraints for OuterSplitter's left pane, and also for both the left and right panes of InnerSplitter.

When the main window is being resized, the desired behavior is for all (or most) of the expansion and contraction to be applied to InnerSplitter's left pane, unless one of the minimum width constraints takes effect. Therefore, I have set the split view Holding Priority for OuterSplitter's left pane to 260 (highest) and 250 for the right pane. Also, the Holding Priority for InnerSplitter's left pane to 245 (lowest) and 255 for the right pane.

I have watched the video for session 232 from WWDC 2012 and thought I was on the right track. My `autolayout` constraints work mostly as desired, but there is one very strange behavior that does not occur with my springs and struts version.

If the split bar of the InnerSplitter is as far right as it will go (InnerSplitter right pane is at its minimum size) AND the OuterSplitter split bar is NOT as far left as it can go, then if you try to drag InnerSplitter's splitter bar farther to the right, then unexpectedly the OuterSplitter's split bar moves to the left causing the InnerSplitter's Left pane to grow and OuterSplitter's left pane to shrink.  My expectation is that no resizing should take place in that case.

It is possible to stop the OuterSplitter's split bar from moving when tugging on the InnerSplitter's split bar that is pinned to the right?  If so, what constraints should be added? Or are some of the `NSSplitViewDelegate` methods still required? Thanks.

BTW, I'm using Xcode 4.6.3 and targeting OSX 10.8.

Comment: Here is a barebones demo: https://github.com/Whiffer/Test-Autolayout

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and got around it by using NSViewControllers within each split view pane so that I didn't directly have split views embedded in split views. It's more code and more complex but it does seem to work.

I never found a solution for when split views are embedded in split views so I'll be interested if anyone has an answer.

Comment: I finally gave up and added a third pane to the outer split view and eliminated the inner split view.  I was not able to achieve all of my desired UI behavior, but at least it works without any strangeness.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you could add an explicit width constraint on `-mouseDown:` in the NSSplitView before calling through to super, then remove it immediately after.

---

Also, it looks like this is fixed in the 10.11 beta!